# Copying methodology from one of my papers to another paper

Tags: paper-submission, stem

After completing a project, I moved on to another project with another group. However, the software and methodology we use is the same. I am currently working on a paper for both groups and a part of the methodology is going to be the same for both papers (keep in mind that the methodology is not something novel, the fundamental methodology is being used for some applied research). Is it unethical (or some other form of wrong) if I use the same writeup for both papers? I must clarify that I am not copying some other group member's work. I wrote the methodology for one paper and want it transferred to another paper (both in progress). This is a STEM paper and there are equations mostly and some writing, and the sequence of the equations and writing are going to be the same if I copy. Also, this is not an entire research methodology, just a part.

Comment: Seems to me repeating a valid, fruitful methodology would be encouraged. Acknowledge it as you would any other.

Answer (score 0):

You will get flagged for similarity, and depending on the journal, may get called out for self-plagiarism.

You obviously cannot change the core of the method, but you may want to consider some of your phrasing to reduce the similarity. This is of course a nuisance, but it is the easiest way for this to sail through without conflict.

Your other option is to publish one of the papers first, then cite it in the subsequent work "this method has recently been described in detail by Author et. al...". Should you want to repeat the description in the second work, you can place it in the SI.